# How to Use a WebClient to Get Page Source When the Page is Loaded from a Script?

Tags: javascript, .net, screen-scraping

Using a WebClient and HtmlAgilityPack, I'm trying to screen-scrape data from the World Bank at this [page](https://www.doingbusiness.org/en/data). However, it appears they use a script to build the page. The script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");
var b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
a.src=document.location.protocol+"//script.crazyegg.com/pages/scripts/0058/1350.js?"+Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/3600000);
a.async=true;a.type="text/javascript";b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)}, 1);
</script>
```

You can view the 1350.js script [here](https://script.crazyegg.com/pages/scripts/0058/1350.js?) (pretty hard to follow).

The page source looks nothing like the rendered the page. Needless to say, my WebClient fetches html that looks nothing like the rendered page, because my WebClient doesn't run the script.

You might say "Just view the page in the browser and copy the html", however that won't help me get the details for all 190 countries linked to on this page, and each country page uses the same trick to delay loading the actual HTML.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to use something that has capabilities close enough to an actual web browser that the website behaves as it would in a real browser - that means executing JavaScript. The most common solution is to use Selenium, Google "web scraping selenium c#".

Comment: Thanks Ian, that looks like a great suggestion.

Comment: Also consider using HttpClient and AngleSharp.